# Migration is required due to Property id has been made required

Tags: realm

it works fine if i change `lateinit var id: String` in the Payment.kt and CartPayment.kt to `var id: String? = ""`, but the problem is i want the id to be required, how can i achieve that ?

The Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
    - Property 'CartPayment.id' has been made required.
    - Property 'Payment.id' has been made required.
```

Model :

```
open class Payment() : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    lateinit var id: String
    var typeValue: Int = 0
    var statusValue: Int = 0
    var value: Double = 0.0
    var referenceNumber: String? = null
```

Note: Payment and CartPayment models are identical except for the class name

Migration.kt

```
class Migration : RealmMigration {

    override fun migrate(realm: DynamicRealm, oldVersion: Long, newVersion: Long) {
        var oldVersion = oldVersion
        val schema = realm.schema

        if (oldVersion == 0L) {
            schema.create("Payment")
                .addField("id", String::class.java, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                .addField("typeValue", Int::class.java)
                .addField("statusValue", Int::class.java)
                .addField("value", Double::class.java)
                .addField("referenceNumber", String::class.java)
            schema.get("Order")!!
                .addRealmListField("payments", schema.get("Payment")!!)
            oldVersion++
        }

        if (oldVersion == 1L) {
            schema.create("CartPayment")
                .addField("id", String::class.java, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                .addField("typeValue", Int::class.java)
                .addField("statusValue", Int::class.java)
                .addField("value", Double::class.java)
                .addField("referenceNumber", String::class.java)
            schema.get("Order")!!
                .addField("cashPaymentAmount", Float::class.java)
                .addField("change", Float::class.java)
            oldVersion++
        }

    }
}
```

App.kt

```
class App: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        Realm.init(this)

        val realmConfig = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(2)
            .migration(Migration())
            .build()
        Realm.getInstance(realmConfig)
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig)

        Fresco.initialize(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.addField("id", String::class.java, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)`
did the trick.

if you declare the variable to be lateinit, make sure to add `FieldAttribute.REQUIRED`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are adding a new field "id" which is primary key (hence required key).
If you do not specify any value while initialisation (lateinit), how will realm migrate all the earlier records, which doesn't have an id, but is required after migration ? Hence the error.

Below solutions might work

1. Either pre-populate the id's (without using lateinit)
2. Transform your earlier records to have id's if they don't have

Check the official examples [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it happened after I have done the Migration.
I have made a non-nullable object in Kotlin and on migration I was creating a nullable wrapper type like Double, Int, etc.
Just use

```
Double::class.java
```

instead of

```
Double::class.javaObjectType
```